# "private" variable in c

Tags: c

Embedded Software where I can just use C.

I am reading the current revision of the circuit board out of an EEPROM.

Based on that revision-number the maximum supported current to the load can be defined.

Now I need that information on plenty of locations in the code (but read-only).
Only the function that reads the EEPROM should be allowed to write the value.
All other functions etc. must not change this value, an error could result in 
damaging the load or board.

Is there a way in c to do this? (NOT C++)

Comment: How about "programming discipline"?

Comment: How about making it a global `static` variable in a source file, and have one function to set it, and one to get it? Then at least the variable can't be accessed and written to directly.

Comment: It would be useful if you were to include some existing code - not least so we can know what data type is used to represent the board revision.

Comment: I want to write good code, where you can't damage things if you don't know what you are doing

Comment: You don’t really want to let people who don’t know what they are doing to have too much freedom to code for you. If they don’t know what they are doing and you let them do it, they will damage things sooner or later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a simple single-core embedded system, this is done by declaring the variable `static` at file scope in the EEPROM driver, such as:

```
static uint16_t max_current;
```

The driver can then access this directly, but `static` prevents any other module from doing so. You give them read-only access by providing a getter function in the same driver:

```
uint16_t get_max_current (void)
{
  return max_current;
}
```

Comment: why is static needed

Comment: If you don't use the `static` keyword then a other file could still access the variable. The `static` makes that variable local to the file it's in. (Not to be confused to when it's used inside a function.)

Comment: @Muperman :  Note that whatever causes `max_current` to be initialised (not shown here) _must_ be called before `get_max_current()` is ever called, otherwise you will get zero, which may or may not be a valid revision, and acting on it may cause incorrect behaviour.  Given that I would suggest that the solution may not provide the robustness you asked for.

Comment: TBH it’s a bit worrying that you don’t know what a static variable is :-o

Comment: It should be noted that this doesn't actually prevent other code from changing it; what it does is make it hard for other code to *find* the value in memory to change.  Assuming you are not talking about malicious code that searches for it, the key distinction would be that something that does out of bound memory access could still *accidentally* corrupt the value in memory, likely along with many other values.  There's no actual memory protection involved here, just declining to provide a ready path to locate it for direct reading or writing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That's a non-issue since modern microcontrollers execute code from flash and don't allow flash to be reprogrammed before getting erased first. So there is no way to get malicious code into the MCU to begin with, unless someone implemented a backdoor through a bootloader. Hence "eeprom" and "embedded"; we aren't talking about your PC here.

Comment: @Lundin - I specifically said "assuming you are **not** talking about malicious code" and gave the example of buggy code accidental overwriting data memory.  That said, flash memory is not ultimately protection against malicious code.  Many modern MCUs (with a few notable exceptions like AVR) can execute from RAM, even those that cannot may be vulnerable to "return oriented programing" and pretty much any hardware is vulnerable to sleeper code inserted by a corrupted build process or toolchain.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a function with a static local and assign it on first use directly from the EEPROM, thereafter the previously initialised value will be returned without re-reading the EEPROM.

Something like (modify the EEPROM read to suit your actual interface):

```
int getBoardRevsion( void )
{
    static int board_revision = -1 ;
    if( board_revision == -1 )
    {
        board_revision = (int)readEeprom( BOARD_REVISION_OFFSET, 1) ;
    }

    return board_revision ;
}
```

`board_revision` is entirely private to all except `getBoardRevsion()`, while strict read-only access is enforced through the function.

Comment: Glad to see you didn't permanently delete it. Was just about to suggest you do what you just did, came to me as an afterthought :)

Answer (score 3):

Use get/set functions. They are a good convention as well. For example (not including header files):

eeprom.c:

```
static uint16_t value = 0;

void eeprom_init(void){
    value = ...;
}

uint16_t get_EEPROM_value(void){return value;}
```

something_else.c:

```
#include "eeprom.h"

int main(void){
    if(get_EEPROM_value() == ...){...}
}
```

Comment: Which language is this, Java?

Comment: It's very minimal C. But my guess is that you found some syntax error to prove otherwise?

Comment: `import` -> `#include`.

Comment: The `import`, probably just a typo?

Comment: If understood correctly, you want to define a global variable inside eeprom.c and not show that variable inside the header eeprom.h. Now you implement the get-"method" and expose that in the eeprom.h?

I think this will do, thanks.

Comment: Exactly so Muperman. You effectively control how other module has access to the variable. @Lundin Seem I did make that mistake yes. Thanks! :)